# Clearing the Service class shared preference value in android

Tags: android

Am working with LocationListener GPS and fused API.When app goes background am getting the value.Am using Service class and Broadcast receiver and am saving the value in to shared prefrence.Once disable and again enable am not getting the preference value.Please help me what is the actual issue.

1.The following code is for BroadcastReciever

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    System.out.println("Alarm Reciver Called");

    if (isMyServiceRunning(this.context, CurrentTenderServiceFragment.GpsServiceFused.class)) {
        System.out.println("already running no need to start again");
    } else {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, CurrentTenderServiceFragment.GpsServiceFused.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }
}

public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (services != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
            if ((serviceClass.getName()).equals(services.get(i).service.getClassName()) && services.get(i).pid != 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}`

2. And i have created service class too...

   ```
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       boolean stopService = false;
       if (intent != null)
           stopService = intent.getBooleanExtra("stopservice", false);
       System.out.println("stopservice " + stopService);
       locationListener = new LocationListener();
       if (stopService)
           stopLocationUpdates();
       else {
           if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
               mGoogleApiClient.connect();
       }

       return START_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       buildGoogleApiClient();
       if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
       }
       initComponents();
   }
   ```

   3. Manifest file

Enabling and Disabling the service by using this,

```
public void enabledBroadcastReceiver() {
    PackageManager pm = DrawerHomeActivity.this.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(DrawerHomeActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    mContext.startService(new Intent(DrawerHomeActivity.this, CurrentTenderServiceFragment.GpsServiceFused.class));
    String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(alarm);
    Intent intent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123456789, intent, 0);
    int type = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
    long interval = 1000 * 50;
    am.setInexactRepeating(type, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pi);
}


  public void disabledBroadcastReceiver() {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(DrawerHomeActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = DrawerHomeActivity.this.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    mContext.stopService(new Intent(DrawerHomeActivity.this, CurrentTenderServiceFragment.GpsServiceFused.class));
    String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(alarm);
    Intent intent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123456789, intent, 0);
    int type = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
    long interval = 1000 * 50;
    am.cancel(pi);
    Intent background = new Intent(DrawerHomeActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    mContext.stopService(background);

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Please specify something more about values and adding those values into shared preferences.

Comment: I have added values on shared prefrence and am not clearing anywhere.But while disabling service preference value also getting cleared.

Comment: what values you are adding and from where

Comment: latitude longitude values are adding and am calculating distance that value also adding.so in background the another distance will calculate and storing that values in to shared prefrence

Comment: in my code onCreate there is a method called initCompontents there am creating sharedprefrence